# What is the difference between running git gc with no options vs the --auto option?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I was looking through the man pages to find what the default behavior of git gc is when no options are passed and couldn't find anything immediately. I originally was under the assumption that the default when using git gc with no options would be the same as git gc --auto.

Is git gc the same as git gc --auto? If not, what's the difference in behavior?

Comment: The difference is spelled out in the manpage, `git help gc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git gc` without the `--auto` always does the cleanup. `git gc --auto` checks if cleanup is necessary first.

Do `git gc` twice in a row and it will repeat the work the second time. But do `git gc --auto` after a `git gc` and it will do nothing.